# How do I parse result from diffChars as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, compare, diff

I need to compare the text of two div tags that will have HTML content.   The result should appear in another div.    While it shows the differences and appears in the div, the HTML is not parsed.

```
<script src="~/js/diff.js"></script>
<script>

comparetxt('divold', 'divnew', 'divresult');

function comparetxt(dold, dnew, dresult) {
    var oldtxt = document.getElementById(dold);
    var newtxt = document.getElementById(dnew);
    var display = document.getElementById(dresult);

    var strnew = newtxt.innerHTML;
    var strold = oldtxt.innerHTML;

    var color = '',
        span = null;

    var diff = Diff.diffChars(strnew, strold),
        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    diff.forEach(function (part) {
        // green for additions, red for deletions
        // grey for common parts
        color = part.added ? 'green' :
            part.removed ? 'red' : 'black';
        span = document.createElement('span');
        span.style.color = color;
        span.appendChild(document
            .createTextNode(part.value));
        fragment.appendChild(span);
    });

    display.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

[image: This is the result.]

Answer (score 0):

`document.createTextNode` escapes html characters. You could use innerHtml to solve your problem.

EDIT: code added for clarity

```
span.innerHtml = part.value
```

Comment: Thank you but if I replace  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(part.value)); with  span.innerHtml = part.value; I get no result.   I'm guessing because it's within a loop.

Comment: I think this has to do with Javascript reference types, you may want to declare span in the loop itself, not outside. @MayB
EDIT: Generally, to avoid this kind of mistake and code clutter, declare variables in the scope they are needed, not on a "global" level